# not able to delete items from the cart in ecommerce shop project that is using react

Tags: reactjs

I am working on an e-commerce project using react.
The users are allowed to click on items and add them to cart.
However, I am unable to delete the items from the cart.

This is the code for ShopContext.jsx:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import all_product from "../Components/Assets/all_product"

export const ShopContext = createContext(null);

const getDefaultCart = () => {
    let cart = {};
    for (let index = 0; index < all_product.length+1; index++) {
        cart[index] = 0;
    }

    return cart;
}

const ShopContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState(getDefaultCart());

    const addToCart = (itemId) => {
        setCartItems((prev) => ({...prev, [itemId]:prev[itemId]+1}));
    }

    const removeFromCart = (itemId) => {
        setCartItems((prev) => ({...prev, [itemId]:prev[itemId]-1}));
        console.log(cartItems);
    }

    const contextValue = {getTotalCartAmount, all_product, cartItems, addToCart, removeFromCart, getTotalCartItems};

    return (
        <ShopContext.Provider value={contextValue} >
            {props.children}
        </ShopContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default ShopContextProvider;
```

This is the code for CartItems.jsx:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import './CartItems.css'
import { ShopContext } from '../../Context/ShopContext';
import remove_icon from '../Assets/cart_cross_icon.png'

const CartItems = () => {
    const {getTotalCartAmount, all_product, cartItems, removeFromCart} = useContext(ShopContext);

    return (
        <div className="cartitems">
            <div className="cartitems-format-main">
                <p>Products</p>
                <p>Title</p>
                <p>Price</p>
                <p>Quantity</p>
                <p>Total</p>
                <p>Remove</p>
            </div>
            <hr />
            {all_product.map((e) => {
                if (cartItems[e.id] > 0) {
                    return <div>
                        <div className="cartitems-format cartitems-format-main">
                            <img src={e.image} alt="" className="cartitems-product-icon" />
                            <p>{e.name}</p>
                            <p>${e.new_price}</p>
                            <button className="cartitems-quantity">{cartItems[e.id]}</button>
                            <p>${e.new_price * cartItems[e.id]}</p>
                            <img className="cartitems-remove-icon" src={remove_icon} alt="" onClick={() => {removeFromCart()}} />
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                    </div>
                }
                return null;
            })}
            <div className="cartitems-down">
                <div className="cartitems-total">
                    <h1>Cart Total</h1>
                    <div>
                        <div className="cartitems-total-item">
                            <p>Subtotal</p>
                            <p>${getTotalCartAmount()}</p>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <div className="cartitems-total-item">
                            <p>Shipping Fee</p>
                            <p>Free</p>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <div className="cartitems-total-item">
                            <h3>Total</h3>
                            <h3>${getTotalCartAmount()}</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button>PROCEED TO CHECKOUT</button>
                </div>
                <div className="cartitems-promocode">
                    <p>If you have a promo code, enter it here...</p>
                    <div className="cartitems-promobox">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Promo Code" />
                        <button>Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CartItems
```

Since both the add to cart and remove from cart functions are similar and one is working while the other one is not working, I am not sure what to try.

This is the link to my project, in case more files are required:
[GitHub](https://github.com/noobuser211/ecommerce)

I have added the sections that I thought were relevant to this question, the rest can be seen in the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function **removeFromCart**, ID product must be sent so the **removeFromCart** can find it and subtract it from it, like this:

```html
    {all_product.map((e) => {
              if (cartItems[e.id] > 0) {
                  return <div>
                        <div className="cartitems-format cartitems-format-main">
                            <img src={e.image} alt="" className="cartitems-product-icon" />
                            <p>{e.name}</p>
                            <p>${e.new_price}</p>
                            <button className="cartitems-quantity">{cartItems[e.id]}</button>
                            <p>${e.new_price * cartItems[e.id]}</p>
                            <img className="cartitems-remove-icon" src={remove_icon} alt="" onClick={() => {removeFromCart(e.id)}} />
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                    </div>
                }
      return null;
    })}
```